# Dynamic image size to fill fixed size div - Javascript/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

***I am javascript/css experienced developer, just need some calculation input from you in the right way to complete my requirement.***

I am working with CSS and JavaScript, and i wanted to fill a div with multiple round shape images,

My requirement is if I have a div with `height of 400px` and `width of 200px` and assume that I have `16 round images`(*there is no any fix number of images just the height and width of div is fixed*), then I want to fill all the image in the div that it looks like filled fixed size div.

I need a flow to create image size dynamic as per the height and width of div, make sure that I don't want any plugin to do this.

**Calculation should be like (for e.g.,)**

> 400px * 200px and 16 images (assume)
>
> then the image size will be 50x50
>
> and setting 8 images in first row and 8 in second row, and the setting padding top and bottom 25px of upper row and bottom row will adjust all 16 images and fill the box of 400x200 size.

[image]

Please guide me on right way

Comment: Use the image in background and repeat it.

Comment: No there is multiple dynamic images from API

Comment: Still you can use multiple images in backgroud.

Comment: but what size will be there of that background image ?

Comment: Since images are round, do you want to leave gaps between images themselves and the div boundaries or the images should somehow overlap them so there are no gaps?

Comment: I need gap between images, let me update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following logic:

```
var wd = parent.clientWidth, he=parent.clientHeight,totalImages=16,url='';
var size = Math.sqrt(wd*he/totalImages);
var di = "<div style='width:"+size +"px; height:"+size +"px; display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center;'><img src='"+url+"'></div>"
parent.append(di);
```

Comment: No @UllasHunka, when we are going to create size for `400x200/16` it returns an image of `5000` of `size`

Comment: My bad, updated the logic please verify with the implementation.